# `span` in `geom_smooth() ` doesn't work with groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm adding smooth lines to my data which are grouped, but the results doesn't change even if I change `span`. Any reason?

```
ggplot(auth.an, aes(x = age, y = auth_eNd_an, color = subregion)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  geom_smooth(method = loess, span = 0.1)
```

Comment: Maybe this reproducible example of using `geom_smooth` with a color/group variable will be of some help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586190/span-argument-not-working-on-graph-on-ggplot2/46613869#46613869

Comment: Can you post your data? It's hard to know what's going on otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late, but try inverted commas:

```
geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.1)
```