# Equivalent of span using geom_smooth() with "gam"

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, gam, loess

This is probably a very basic question but I haven't found an answer yet. Is there an equivalent to the `span` argument in the `geom_smooth` function when `method = "gam"`? I am not familiar with GAM's in general so I would appreciate any input on that. I want to add a more flexible (wigglier) smoother to data with n > 1'000 and `method = "loess"` takes a lot of time to calculate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mgcv::gam` by default optimizes the smoothness using penalized regression. You can switch that off and specify the smoothness manually with the `k` parameter:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", 
              formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", fx = TRUE, k = 20))
```

You should probably study the documentation of package mgcv.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for. I already guessed that number of knots were involved in this but I couldn't figure out how to get this done.